# How can I export a VM to a VMDK in VMware Workstation?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vmdk

I have a Windows 10 VM in VMware Workstation 16 Pro. My host operating system is also Windows 10.

When I created the VM, I selected to split the disk.

How can I export the VM to a single VMDK file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe` command-line tool (located in the VMware Workstation Pro installation folder) to convert virtual disks. Running `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe` with no arguments provides help, which shows the following example to convert a split disk (`sourceDisk.vmdk`) to a growable, monolithic disk (`destinationDisk.vmdk`):

```
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -r sourceDisk.vmdk -t 0 destinationDisk.vmdk
```

After it succcessfully creates the new disk, you should be able to safely delete `sourceDisk.vmdk` (and all of its extents, i.e. the `sourceDisk-s###.vmdk` files) and to rename `destinationDisk.vmdk` to the original `.vmdk` filename. (I recommend moving the old `.vmdk` files somewhere else and testing the new `.vmdk` before actually deleting any files.)